# Sealing a loose deck-mount bath faucet

Tags: plumbing, faucet, bathtub

Does anyone know how I can seal/tighten following loose deck mounted bathtub faucet? Is there any waterproof double sided tape for this? I lifted it up in the first image below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That needs to be tightened from below, not stuck down from above.

Comment: For now till you can do it properly, silicone placed under it should seal water from getting under it.  It will hold it to the deck, but not be solid enough to use as a handle.

Comment: A picture of the mounting from underneath will help us help you figure out how to tighten it down. It's most likely a nut of some sort, so in the process of taking the picture, you'll probably figure it out yourself. If you can't reach it with any of the wrenches you currently own, search this site for "basin wrench" to see the tool you need, then go buy one.

Comment: @FreeMan you're making the generous assumption that the builders provided ***any*** access for maintenance. Modern ones usually don't, and then you have to figure out  if you can get in by breaking the wall to left, cutting into a ceiling below, or if you have to break tile to get in there. Access doors are really nice - put one in for the next time when you've found your way in there. Until then, I agree that silicone caulking around the base (and taping the faucet to hold it down until that cures, since it wants to lean) followed by NOT using it as a handle is the best stop-gap.

Comment: Don't the modern ones need access doors more, than the old ones.

Comment: Thanks all. I added one more picture from underneath the main loose base showing a nut which I think should be tighten. Given there is no access for maintenance ... I guess breaking the tiles would be the only option left.

Comment: @crip659 they all need access. The current-era **builders** generally don't provide access. They have no intent of living there or being held responsible when things break if they last until the check clears. The time and slight cost of installing an acess is seen as a profit drain, not a selling point, and the access later is seen as "Somebody Else's Problem."  For which, read _Life,_The_Universe,_and_Everything_ by Douglas Adams.

Comment: @Stat is that an exterior wall to the right side or is it another room from which you could knock a hole through the wall?

Comment: @brhans that's the wall for showers room.